# In ggplot2 ,how to change legend text to percent format

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In R ,how to change legend text to percent format.

[image: how to change legend text to percent format]

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- data.frame(category=letters,data_seq=c(1:length(letters)),
                        value=rnorm(length(letters))/10)

plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=data_seq,y=category,fill=value))+
  geom_tile()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use labels=scales::percent inside scale_fill_continuous(). Remember to install scales package using `install.packages("scales")`

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- data.frame(category=letters,data_seq=c(1:length(letters)),
                        value=rnorm(length(letters))/10)

plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=data_seq,y=category,fill=value))+
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

[image]